# Replace Parent View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have following view controller hierarchy with Parent children relationship.

**VC1 -- VC2 -- VC3 -- VC4 -- VC5**

Each view controller is children of predecessor.

I have used code -

```
   [parentVC addChildViewController:childVC];

   [childVC.view setFrame:parentVC.view.frame];

   [parentVC.view addSubview:childVC.view];

   [childVC didMoveToParentViewController:parentVC];
```

Now, I want **to replace VC1 to another view controller, say VC0 in this hierarchy after an action from VC5** i.e. After removing VC2, I want to have VC0 instead of VC1. How to achieve this?

Comment: Why are the relationships so deep? How does this appear on the UI?

Comment: I'm setting frame of children's view as that of parent. Please check updated code. it will give you an idea.

Answer (score 2):

`UINavigationController` provides a [`-setViewControllers:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers%3aanimated%3a) method that you can use to modify the navigation stack. It's usually used to restore an app to the state it was in when the user left the app. From the docs:

> Use this method to update or replace the current view controller stack
>   without pushing or popping each controller explicitly. In addition,
>   this method lets you update the set of controllers without animating
>   the changes, which might be appropriate at launch time when you want
>   to return the navigation controller to a previous state.

That said, using this method to replace view controllers in the stack sounds like a poor plan from a UI point of view -- it seems likely to confuse users, who fully expect parent controllers not to transmogrify into something completely different.

Comment: Well, I'm agree with you, that it is bad idea to replace parent View Controller. Also I'm not using UINavigationController since I have to provide some fancy animations while showing another view. Any work around you suggest?

Comment: The tools are all there -- UIViewController provides methods for removing and adding children and for getting the list of current children. It sounds like the main problem is deciding who should coordinate the switch, and that's probably something that you have to decide based on the needs of your app. I'd look first at whatever object normally manages VC1 -- the app delegate, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Delegation is the appropriate solution, where the source parent (the delegate) is passed down through the chain to the leaf controller (that wants to callback).

The fact that this is unpleasant indicates that what you're trying to do is a bit weird. But, not knowing the requirement limits larger suggestions.

If you want to cheat your way out (you shouldn't) then posting a notification is much less code. Using blocks as the implementation of the delegate pattern is medium code.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how delegation will help? Main problem is I want to replace superview keeping added view as it is on screen.

Comment: You said the action was from V5, so you need to message back to the root so the parent and view can be switched out. Just remove one parent and add the new one (and swap the parent view).

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to 'remove one parent and add the new one (and swap the parent view)'?

Comment: You have the code in your question, just get the first child VC and set the new parent and superview.